# AngularJs: UI Router browser refresh, move to first child state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular UI Router and not using HTML5 mode. Below is router configuration. I am using nested views for each step of an order processing app.
Each step of ordering process is dependent on previous step
My problem is that on browser refresh on Step 2 or Step 3 of the ordering process; all input data is lost and so I want the user to be redirected to initial ***Step 1*** of ordering process

```
  $stateProvider
        .state('wizard', {
            url: "/wizard",
            templateUrl: 'template/newOrder.cshtml',
            controller: 'createOrderController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            data: { pageTitle: 'Wizard form' }
        })
        .state('wizard.step_one', {
            url: '/step_one',
            templateUrl: 'template/step1.cshtml',
            controller: 'orderStep1Controller',
            controllerAs:'vm',
            data: { pageTitle: 'Wizard form' }
        })
        .state('wizard.step_two', {
            url: '/step_two',
            templateUrl: 'template/step2.cshtml',
            controller: 'orderStep2Controller',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            data: { pageTitle: 'Wizard form' }
        })
        .state('wizard.step_three', {
            url: '/step_three',
            templateUrl: 'template/step3.cshtml',
            controller: 'orderStep3Controller',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            data: { pageTitle: 'Wizard form' }
        })
    .state('wizard.step_four', {
        url: '/step_four',
        templateUrl: 'template/step4.cshtml',
        controller: 'orderStep4Controller',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        data: { pageTitle: 'Wizard form' }
    })
    ;
```

Regards,

Comment: create a service that checks the input data when the controller loads and if the validation fails send them to step 1. OR use local storage/cookies to store their data

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the `/wizard` state is not actually doing anything other than holding the nested views.

You may need to change a few things around to make it an abstracted view to hold all the states including changing the `neworder.cshtml` to its own state:

```
.state('wizard', {
        url: "/wizard",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'template/newOrder.cshtml',
        controller: 'createOrderController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        data: { pageTitle: 'Wizard form' }
    })
```

More in depth information and how the abstraction can be used can be found [Ui-Router GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state)

It includes gret info about how to do urlRouterRedirects which may be of use in this case depending on when you want it to happen. You could say when you land on the wizard view to redirect to neworder (below for example)

> $urlRouterProvider.when('/wizard', '/wozard/neworder');

If you want to catch it after a specific event you can also use `.otherwise`.

> $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/otherwise');

The /otherwise url must be defined on a state as usual:

> $stateProvider
>       .state("otherwise", { url : '/otherwise'...})

Comment: Thanks Mark for your comment; I tried making wizard state abstract and making changes you suggested but it didn't work for me... I feel moving to a default state on refreshing browser manually or through F5 would be something baked into UI Router.. Will explore more.. Regards

Comment: are you open to using the ui-router 1.0 alpha release? it has transition hooks that you can use to do this.  If so let me know I'll write up an answer.